# redirect 301 subdomain to same subdomain but in new folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect 301 subdomain to same subdomain but in a new folder.

So I want to redirect `http://sub.example.com/(.*)` to `http://sub.example.com/folder/`

But when I go to `folder` the page does not open.

**Notes**:

- I put the `.htaccess` in main subdomain.
- I also get a redirect loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your first comment, try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ folder/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: yes works 
but if i go to links like this
subdomain/one.html
subdomain/two.html
subdomain/three.html
etc ..

it not work to redirect to new folder !
i want to redirect it in new main page in folder .. like this
subdomain/one.html -> subdomain/folder/one.html
subdomain/two.html -> subdomain/folder/two.html
subdomain/three.html -> subdomain/folder/three.html
etc ..

and thanks for all ..

Comment: Please experiment with my update.